# How can we create the another select box with some options through JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I would like to create another select box from a select box value. through Jquery.

We have applied this codes and it's not working at the moment.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var rooms = $("#rooms");
    var ROOMS = rooms.val() ;

    var max_adults_a = 3;
    var min_adults_a = 2;

    var max_adults = max_adults_a; 
    var min_adults = min_adults_a;
    var num = min_adults * ROOMS;
    ROOMS.change(function() {
      while (num <= max_adults_a * ROOMS) {
        $('#person').append($('<option></option>').val(num).html(num)
      )};
    });
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Populating Select Boxes</h1>
  Category:
  <select name="rooms" id="rooms">
     <option Selected value="">Select</option>
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
  person
  <select name="person" id="person">
  </select>
</body>
```

we have 2 select box one for rooms, and other for Persons, We have a list for Rooms, but we have to update the Persons according to the rooms size, if we have a room type "3" then the persons will be allowed for this room is 6,7,8,9.

The options for Persons will change accordingly. 
Please  provide me suitable solutions
Thanks 
Rod

Comment: `category` is not defined anywhere. Surely this blows up?

Comment: we have updated the code, there was some this wrong in the code, now it's ok.

Comment: both the select box have default value is blank, at first we select room type 3 then the options value will be change for person's select box.

Comment: You're setting ROOMS to the value of the select on document.ready. That value appears to be -1 since you set the default value in the markup. It appears your intention is to have ROOMS be a jquery object, not a value.

Comment: kinakuta, please check we have updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var max_adults = 3; 
    var min_adults = 2;
    $('#rooms').change(function(){
        var room_num = $(this).val();
        var options = '';
        for (var i = min_adults * room_num; i <= max_adults * room_num; i++) {
            options += '<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>'
        }
        $('#person').html(options);
    });
    $('#rooms').change();
});
```

Comment: what will be the HTML part, it's still remain same ?

Comment: @Rodger Yes, the HTML part remain same.

Comment: Thanks for giving me this support , Thanks

Answer (score 1):

On [jsfiddl.net](http://jsfiddle.net/sP3Tu/9/)

```
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
  <script>
       $(document).ready(function () {
         var rooms = $("#rooms");
         var ROOMS = rooms.val() ;

         var max_adults_a = 3;
         var min_adults_a = 2;

         var max_adults = max_adults_a; 
         var min_adults = min_adults_a;

         $("#rooms").change(function() {
            $('#person').html("");
           var selectedRoom = parseInt($("#rooms option:selected").val(), 10)
           var num = min_adults * selectedRoom ;
           while (num <= max_adults_a * selectedRoom ) {
             $('#person').append($('<option></option>').val(num).html(num));
             num++;
           }
        });
     });
  </script>    
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Populating Select Boxes</h1>
  Category:
  <select name="rooms" id="rooms">
     <option Selected value="">Select</option>
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
  person
  <select name="person" id="person">
  </select>
</body>
```